# Deploying NodeJs Express Rest API to Windows 10 IoT

Tags: node.js, rest, express, iot, windows-10-iot-core

Node noob, Windows 10 IoT noob, senior .net dev here.
I've been able to get a few of the samples to work, even got an led on a breadboard to be controllable through a nodejs server.
I am using the latest chakra core files and have all of the packages installed on my dev machine, which is pretty clean.

I am guessing its not able to install the packages that are specified in the packages.json file, here is the excerpt:

"express": "~4.0.0",
"morgan": "~1.0.0",
"mongoose": "~3.6.13",
"body-parser": "~1.0.1"

If it is the packages, how does one go about deploying nodejs applications with packages to windows iot? I considered just copying the application to the iot device and starting it manually, no luck. I also need the ms assemblies that allow me to interface code with the gpio.

I am now trying to get a simple rest api to windows 10 iot, and am having some trouble. I followed this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4), and its working if I use the non Universal Windows template on my machine. However, when I try to use this template (Basic Node.js Express 4 Application (Universal Windows)), and make it into the same application, the app is deployed, but the debugger fails, looking at the debug section of the windows 10 iot device, I have the following:
Report signature

Package Full Name : test.iot.nodejs.express.njsproj_1.0.0.0_arm__b4gtp05xzgr10
Application Name : praid:App
Application Version : 10.0.10586.63
Application Timestamp : 568b3d9f
Fault Module Name : ucrtbase.dll
Fault Module Version : 10.0.10586.63
Fault Module Timestamp : 568b34eb
Exception Offset : 000351ed
Exception Code : c0000409
Exception Data : 00000005
EventTime

January 26, 2016 at 10:22:17 PM PST

Link to Watson bucket

133280376927
FriendlyEventName

Stopped working

AppName

test.iot.nodejs.express.njsproj_b4gtp05xzgr10!App

AppPath

C:\windows\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe

Comment: You can take a look at this article https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/12/bringing-node-js-to-windows-10-iot-core/ 
I am no expert in windows OS, but I would refrain from using nodejs on iot, given that the support is still limited and probably will stay limited

Comment: Thank you, I followed this example a few days ago. If not node.js, what other web server does windows 10 iot support? Cordova? I'm not sure I want to go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Edward, regarding the web server question, you might want to check out this example: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/BlinkyWebServer.htm

Comment: Thank you for that link. I'll try it out.

Comment: I just tried it, it worked. Interesting deployment strategy, have to deploy two applications. In any case, I am still stuck with the same issue, and is the the need for a rest api.