# how to deploy nodejs rest api with express framework on production server windows

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, deployment

I have created a node.js rest api created using express framework for routing. I have used [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)

Now I want to deploy that rest api on actual production server. How to achieve that thing.

I have gone through below links.

[Deploy node js application with express framework on production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600952/deploy-node-js-application-with-express-framework-on-production-mode)  --- Only for linux. I need for windows.

[Deploying NodeJs Express Rest API to Windows 10 IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064933/deploying-nodejs-express-rest-api-to-windows-10-iot) -- a little bit similar  problem but no solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652869/2810015 -- this said to run npm start on production server after copying all of the files on server. But this is not working fine either.

Any help will be highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You use pm2?

Usually I use it to start the application. It works for both windows and linux. He leaves the service initated, and in case something happens that knocks the service up again.

You install it on the server, and instead of using it

```
node server.js
```

You use the command below

```
pm2 server.js start
```

Link: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/advanced/pm2-module-system/